# Dynamic SUM() while using Sum(Case) on a VIEW in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I am trying to create a VIEW where I should have the following columns:

**Clinic_id | Result_month_id | AVF | AVC | AVG | Other | Total_Days**

Total_Days should be calculated dynamically using (AVF+AVC+[AVG]+Other).

The SQL Query is:

```
CREATE VIEW Rate AS 

SELECT  
clinic_id, result_month_id, 
sum(case v_id when 'ula' then [days] else 0 end) as AVF,
sum(case v_id 
        when 'ter' then [days] 
        when 'theter' then [days] 
        when 'p_theter' then [days] 
        when 't_theter' then [days] 
        else 0 
    end) as AVC,
sum(case v_id when 's_graft' then [days] else 0 end) as [AVG],
sum(case v_id when 'other' then [days] else 0 end) as [Other] 

FROM [Server].[DBName].[TableName]

GROUP BY clinic_id, result_month_id
;
```

I have tried to add the final column by using

```
  SELECT 
   columns,
   .... 
   (AVF+AVC+[AVG]+Other)as Total_Days

  FROM
  (SELECT 
       the QUERY displayed above...
  )q
```

But the above did not work. Any idea how can I dynamically create the Total of the four columns that I am creating on the VIEW?

Comment: This should work. What is the problem?

Comment: _But the above did not work_ Did you get an error message?

Comment: problem was near the FROM statement before Q and the ; sign of the VIEW was getting added by mistake. It worked now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery for this:

```
CREATE VIEW Rate AS 
select t.*, AVC + [AVG] + Other as TotalDays
from (SELECT clinic_id, result_month_id, 
             sum(case v_id when 'ula' then [days] else 0 end) as AVF,
             sum(case v_id 
                     when 'ter' then [days] 
                     when 'theter' then [days] 
                     when 'p_theter' then [days] 
                     when 't_theter' then [days] 
                     else 0 
                 end) as AVC,
             sum(case v_id when 's_graft' then [days] else 0 end) as [AVG],
             sum(case v_id when 'other' then [days] else 0 end) as [Other] 
      FROM [Server].[DBName].[TableName]
      GROUP BY clinic_id, result_month_id
     ) t
```

Comment: t.* is a good idea then writing all the column names again. This is much cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: @shaz . . . You will hear the advice to never use `select *`.  Although generally a good practice, `select *` is quite useful when selecting result from subqueries or CTEs.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Will remember that.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is going to be to use a CTE.

```
CREATE VIEW Rate AS 

WITH CalculatedValues AS (
    SELECT  
        clinic_id, result_month_id, 
        sum(case v_id when 'ula' then [days] else 0 end) as AVF,
        sum(case v_id 
                when 'ter' then [days] 
                when 'theter' then [days] 
                when 'p_theter' then [days] 
                when 't_theter' then [days] 
                else 0 
            end) as AVC,
        sum(case v_id when 's_graft' then [days] else 0 end) as [AVG],
        sum(case v_id when 'other' then [days] else 0 end) as [Other] 
    FROM [Server].[DBName].[TableName]
    GROUP BY clinic_id, result_month_id
    )
SELECT *, (AVF+AVC+[AVG]+Other)as Total_Days
FROM CalculatedValues;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a view on the view:

```
CREATE VIEW Rate AS ...

CREATE VIEW Rate_All AS
SELECT *, AVC + [AVG] + Other as TotalDays
FROM Rate;
```